# remove dollar sign on from price of product in open classifieds

Tags: javascript, php, string

Hello Everyone I need help on my code. I try to remove the dollar sign but i cant it is showing error every time i edit the code.- (i18n::money_format).

```
<?= FORM::label('price', __('Price'), array('for'=>'price'))?>
                                    <div class="input-prepend">
                                        <?= FORM::input('price', Request::current()->post('price'), array('placeholder' => html_entity_decode(html_entity_decode(i18n::money_format(1))), 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'price', 'type'=>'text', 'data-error' => __('Please enter only numbers.')))?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?endif?>
```

Comment: Show the error please, also show how you have tried to edit the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `i18n::money_format(1)` will return the value including the currency set in the application or the server, if you do not want the currency symbol, just skip using the function to format it at all.

It would probably be better to let the user choose what type of currency they want displayed (and converted to) if you are dealing with multiple currencies.
It's also possible currency on your server/in the php code to display another currency if you wish, by setting the `LC_MONETARY` locale with the `setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');` function.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the money_format function in your code which coverts the number to the locale currency.

Check here http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_money_format.asp

if you do not need the currency format , just do not use it.